# how to access nested struct objects

Tags: c, struct

```
typedef struct _imat {
 int **m_mat;
 int rows, cols;
} intMat;

typedef struct _banker {
 intMat A;
 intMat M;
 int *C;
 int numRes;
 int numProcs;
 } banker;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  banker *b,c;
  b = &c;
 matInit((*b).A,(*b).numProcs,(*b).numRes);
}
```

I am trying to access `intMat A` in `_banker` struct but getting error:

```
"expected ‘struct intMat *’ but argument is of type ‘intMat’ void matInit(intMat *mat,int rows, int cols){"
```

Comment: `matInit(&(b->A),b->numProcs,b->numRes);`

Answer (score 0):

`(*b).A` is of type `intMat`

However `matInit` is expecting a `intMat *`

So replace `(*b).A` with `&(*b).A`, for the "&" will make it a pointer

Comment: use matInit(&b->A, b->numProcs, b->numRes); instead use of the deference and dot operator.